# Servlet Mapping Error in Path

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and Servlets.

I have two JSP pages Index.jsp and Edit.jsp and one Controller.java.

1. Index.jsp

   ```
    <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Index</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <Form action="/ch2/servletController/Controller">
       <h1>Hello World!</h1>
       <a href="Edit.jsp"> Click here </a>
       <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="gotoEdit" />

       </Form>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Edit.jsp

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Edit</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="Controller">
       <h3>This is a simple HTML page that has a form in it.</h3>
       <h3>If there is a value for the hobby in the query string, then it is used to initialize the hobby element. 

       </h3>
       <p>
       Hobby:    
       <input type="text" name="hobby" value="${param.hobby}" />
       <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="processButton" />
       </p>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   package ch2.servletController;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class Controller extends HttpServlet
    {
    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String address;
     if (request.getParameter("processButton") !=null)
     {
    address = "Process.jsp";
    }
    else if (request.getParameter("confirmButton") !=null)
    {
       address = "Confirm.jsp";
    }
    else
    {
     address = "Edit.jsp";
       }
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
       request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      }}
   ```

Web Xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ch2.servletController.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ch2/servletController/Controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So the problem is when I run the index.jsp page and click "Edit" button, it goes to an error.

![The error I receive][4]

Kindly Suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggestion:

1) Since you are referring Edit.jsp in href, make sure that both jsp's are under same folder.
   Best way would be make href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/Edit.jsp"

2) Apply the same for form action i.e

action="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/ch2/servletController/Controller"

Hope this helps your cause.

Comment: Thank you Suyash, but it's not working.
Basically, My Controller is in Classes.ch2.servletController folder
and Index and Edit is in WEB-INF folder.
I have also changed the path in web.xml in <url-pattern> as /ch2/servletController/Controller 
Please suggest...

Comment: In web.xml,Change URL pattern to "/controller" an update the same in Jsp's form action attribute to action="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/controller"
this will work.

Comment: Thanks Suyash, Yes I know it's working in that case but why not when I am mapping it?

Answer (score 0):

In Edit.jsp, form action is Controller, which should be corrosponding url-pattern of servlet in web.xml file. In your case, if you change Edit.jsp form action to form action="/ch2/servletController/Controller", jsp code snippet will to find the Servlet.